# Hide div from page layout after print button click

Tags: lightning, javascript, printpdf

In my lightning component, I have a div with `aura:id = "hidefromPDF"`.
On Print button click I want to hide the div from page print. 
I tried the following code on button click

```
{
   var hidefromPDF = component.find('hidefromPDF');
   $A.util.addClass(hidefromPDF,'slds-hide');
   window.print();
   $A.util.removeClass(hidefromPDF,'slds-hide');
}
```

But it's not hiding the div from the page print. Do I missing something here?

Comment: Did you see what is it giving when you console.log(hidefromPDF)?

Comment: console log gives : {get: ƒ, getEvent: ƒ, superRender: ƒ, superAfterRender: ƒ, superRerender: ƒ, …}. However, If I comment $A.util.removeClass() code and return to the page that particular div not visible there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a lag between updating the DOM and sending the elements to the window.print. I would suggest, using another approach where you can hide the element/div which you don't want to print using a media query.

Example -

Give a specific class to that div

```
<div class="hideInPrint">
   ...content which you don't want to send to the print 
</div>
```

Style Component

```
@media print {
    .THIS .hideInPrint {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, It worked. After fixing some minor issues(misspelled class name).

Comment: But may Iknow what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I think while showing/hiding the element using the toggle, it's not reflecting immediately on the DOM and that could be an issue. It's just an assumption which I am making. In the solution I provided, we have set explicitly that this element should not be visible when a print is performed. Eventually, we get rid of the toggling class and that's why it worked.